# Backbone: Collection is empty when view is initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem, and I think my pattern is wrong.

I am not sure how to use `collection.fetch()` to get data on the initial render.

I am calling the Flickr API to build some images.  When clicking the button the next page value should be passed to the `collection.url` and a new ajax request submitted to re-render the template.  However, I can not get the collection to pull in data from Flickr and pass it to the template on the initial render.

Here is a fiddle to my current code:  http://jsfiddle.net/48WpV/

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var urlParameters = {
  page: 1,
  api_key:'a2978e5ce30c337e3b639172d3e1a0d1',
  tags: 'cats',
  method: 'flickr.photos.search',
  per_page: 3,
  format: 'json'
};

var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  default: {
    photos: '',
    stat: ''   
  }
});

var TheCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: TheModel,

  url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest'

});

var TheView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.js-container',

  initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new TheCollection();

    this.fetchData();

    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);

    return this;
  }, 

  render: function () {        
    var temp = _.template( $('#List').html(), {collection: this.collection.toJSON()} );      
    this.$el.html(temp);   

    return this;
  },

  fetchData: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.collection.fetch({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        data: urlParameters,
        jsonp:'jsoncallback',
        success: function (data) {
           console.log('self.collection =',self.collection.toJSON()); 
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('ERROR!!!');
        }
    });    

    return this;
  },

  events: {
    'click .js-button': 'nextPage'   
  },

  nextPage: function () {
    urlParameters.page = urlParameters.page + 1;
    this.fetchData();

    return this;
  }

});

var theView = new TheView();
theView.render();
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="List">
    <button class="js-button">Click for the next page</button>
    <% console.log('templates collection=',collection) %>

    <% _.each(collection, function (element, index) { %>
        <% _.each(element.photos.photo, function(ele, i) { %>

           <img src="http://farm<%- ele.farm %>.staticflickr.com/<%- ele.server %>/<%- ele.id %>_<%- ele.secret %>_m.jpg" />

        <% }); %>

    <% }); %>

</script>


<div class="js-container">

</div>
```

Comment: (1) `fetch` is an AJAX call, you have to wait until it finishes before you can do anything with its results. (2) `self.collection = data` serves no purpose, `data` should be the collection already and `fetch` updates the collection in-place.

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you for the explanation.  It was not clear to me if the collection would be updated after the fetch or if I had to re-assign the value of the response to it.

Comment: I re-opened because you have *two* problems: the AJAX problem and the `url` problem.

Comment: FYI, if you want to keep the other data in memory (either because you want to show them all at once, or because you want the user to be able to navigate back and avoid having to re-fetch the earlier data), put `remove: false` in your `fetch` argument. Then it will only add new models and merge existing ones.

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you for taking a look.  I updated the code, but I an empty collection is passed to the template in the initial `render()`.  You mentioned binding `render()` to the collection but I am not sure I understand.  Is that the same as using `listenTo()`?

Comment: You could `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render)` and then call `fetch` with `reset: true`. Something like this version of Rami's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gu8v5/ . Or you could move a few things around and do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8993M/

Comment: @muistooshort thank you for the help.  I updated the fiddle like this actually http://jsfiddle.net/n8qd2/ and it looks like it's working though I'm not sure if it's totally optimal.  For the longest time I thought listenTo would be a `change` and not a `reset` until looked into your comment below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following issues in your code:

1) You need to update the url at every fetch.

```
fetchData: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.collection.fetch({
        url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?page=' + pageNumber + '&api_key=a2978e5ce30c337e3b639172d3e1a0d1&tags=kitten&method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=3&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
           self.collection = data; 
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('ERROR!!!');
        }
    });
```

2) you need to remove '1' from your url

```
url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?page=' + pageNumber + '1&api_key=a2978e5ce30c337e3b639172d3e1a0d1&tags=kitten&method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=3&format=json&jsoncallback=?
```

to be

```
  url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?page=' + pageNumber + '&api_key=a2978e5ce30c337e3b639172d3e1a0d1&tags=kitten&method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=3&format=json&jsoncallback=?'
```

3) you need to change `pageNumber + 1;` to `pageNumber += 1;`  to actually increase the value.

4) you don't this line `self.collection = data;` calling fetch() alone will assign the returned values to the collection.

5) and of course, you need to render after each fetch

here is a working code: http://jsfiddle.net/48WpV/7/

Comment: Your fiddle still doesn't work because `fetch` is an AJAX call and nothing is listening for any events it generate. You'd need to include `reset:true` in the `fetch` options and bind `render` to `'reset'` events.

Comment: @muistooshort I guess I am trying to get his code to work synchronously (it works now). Following your approach might be even cleaner than calling render after each fetch, but I will leave it to OP to update the code based on your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Thanks Rami!  I apologize for the other errors in the code, it was the fetch I was not sure about and so had not noticed the others.  Thank you!

Comment: @RamiEnbashi I must misunderstand the collection.url.  I thought that the `var pageNumber` would update that value to 2 in the collection.url after the first click.  Thank you for the other suggestions as well.  I was so wrapped up with figuring out the fetch that I didn't notice them.